# Python try / except / else loop does both the try and else actions

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm running a Python script to post a Tweet if the length is short enough with an exception for errors and an else statement for messages that are too long.

When I run this, it posts the Tweet and still gives the Tweet too long message. Any idea why that is happening and how to make it work as intended?

```
if len(tweet_text) <= (280-6):
    try:    
        twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
        twitter.update_status(status=tweet_text)
    except TwythonError as error:
            print(error)
    else:
        print("Tweet too Long. Please try again.")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` be aligned with your `if` not the `try/except`?

Comment: `else` will execute , if there are no exceptions in your `try` block. So I think its normal. And as @IainShelvington said, you should consider aligning it with `if` block, as it seems logical

Comment: There is no loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that *must be executed* if the try clause does not raise an exception. (emphasis added)

Spaces/Tabs matter in Python.

What your snippet says in common English
is "Try to post the tweet, unless there's an error, then print the error.  If there's not an error, print 'Tweet too long.  Please try again.'"

What you want is:

```
if len(tweet_text) <= (280-6):
    try:    
        twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
        twitter.update_status(status=tweet_text)
    except TwythonError as error:
        print(error)
else:
    print("Tweet too Long. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 2):

The first string is checking the length of the tweet. Move the `else` four spaces back. Because `try/except` construction can be `try/except/else` construction